# I have 28 country specific databases with same tables, want to select values from a particular table in all databases

Tags: sql-server

I have many country specific databases with same tables, want to select values from a particular table of all databases.

How to implement join in this scenario?

```
SELECT column1, column2 FROM db1.table1 
SELECT column1, column2 FROM db2.table1
```

Comment: union all, look here http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp. But at least for ms sql you need  database_name.schema_name.object_name

Comment: op, if any of the answers have solved your issue then please feel free to upvote the relevant ones and mark one as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION :

```
SELECT column1, column 2 FROM db1.table1 
UNION
SELECT column1, column 2 FROM db2.table1
UNION
SELECT column1, column 2 FROM db3.table1
```

...

Comment: It's worth noting that UNION will remove any duplicate values you have in the data. UNION ALL will keep the full list as-is.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `UNION ALL` operator;

```
SELECT column1, column2 FROM Database1Name.SchemaName.table1 
UNION ALL
SELECT column1, column2 FROM Database2Name.SchemaName.table1
UNION ALL
SELECT column1, column2 FROM Database3Name.SchemaName.table1
```

If you're going to be calling this from different places then it may make sense to stick this into a view and then just call the view in your `FROM` statement;

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[VW_Table1_Total_Results]
AS
    SELECT column1, column2 FROM Database1Name.SchemaName.table1 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT column1, column2 FROM Database2Name.SchemaName.table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT column1, column2 FROM Database3Name.SchemaName.table1
```

Then you can just do this select which will make it easier to read if you're then doing joins to any other tables or any further calculations on the results;

```
SELECT
Column1
,Column2
FROM VW_Table1_Total_Results
```